# SharePoint site documentation

Tags: documentation

Are there any good documentation templates for SharePoint sites available? I have created a few SharePoint team sites and I would like to document all list, doc libraries, permissions...etc

Comment: Wiki libraries do a pretty good job for that.

Comment: Thanks. Where would I find a SharePoint wiki library or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Document what?  Are you wanting to you SharePoint to store documentation or are you wanting to document your SharePoint structure, etc?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to Document my SharePoint structure.

Answer (score 1):

A Wiki Page Library is a type of Document Library that contains Wiki Pages. Wiki Pages are very easy to edit - you can simply paste content directly from Word if you want, and all formatting, including images, tables, etc., will be kept.  Wiki Pages also have a nifty syntax for linking to other pages which can be used to link supplemental info or create a table of contents.

In my experience Wiki Libraries are far superior to Word docs sitting in document libraries because users are much more inclined to *actually read them*.

Wiki Page Libraries are really well suited to documentation, and the web is full of wiki-formatted documentation for software projects, though not necessarily SharePoint wikis. Off the top of my head I can think of [MineCraft](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Wiki), [Blender](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual), [Open Office](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation), and [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Documentation).